# Image upload error: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string

Tags: node.js, firebase, postman, firebase-admin, busboy

I am building backend functions with node.js and firebase. I used BusBoy to build an image upload function;

I check my code again and again, changed the image with a smaller size one (like 140 kb) and tried to detect the problem and from the code I thought that it is some kind of problem to write the path name of the uploaded file, in `firebase serve` it gives the error:

> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined

```
  exports.uploadImage = (req, res) => {
  const BusBoy = require('busboy');
  const path = require('path');
  const os = require('os');
  const fs = require('fs');

  const busboy = new BusBoy({ headers: req.headers });

  let imageToBeUploaded = {};
  let imageFileName;

  busboy.on('file', (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) => {
    console.log(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype);
    if (mimetype !== 'image/jpeg' && mimetype !== 'image/png') {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Wrong file type submitted' });
    }
    // my.image.png => ['my', 'image', 'png']
    const imageExtension = filename.split('.')[filename.split('.').length - 1];
    // 32756238461724837.png
    imageFileName = `${Math.round(
      Math.random() * 1000000000000
    ).toString()}.${imageExtension}`;
    const filepath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), imageFileName);
    imageToBeUploaded = { filepath, mimetype };
    file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filepath));
  });
  busboy.on('finish', () => {
    admin
      .storage()
      .bucket()
      .upload(imageToBeUploaded.filepath, {
        resumable: false,
        metadata: {
          metadata: {
            contentType: imageToBeUploaded.mimetype
          }
        }
      })
      .then(() => {
        const imageUrl = `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/${
          config.storageBucket
        }/o/${imageFileName}?alt=media`;
        return db.doc(`/users/${req.user.handle}`).update({ imageUrl });
      })
      .then(() => {
        return res.json({ message: 'image uploaded successfully' });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
        return res.status(500).json({ error: 'something went wrong' });
      });
  });
  busboy.end(req.rawBody);
};
```

When I look the details, I realized that the problem is in this line: 
`.upload(imageToBeUploaded.filepath,`

I am sending post request from Postman

Is there anybody to help me ?

Full error message:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string.
Received type undefined 
> at validateString (internal/validators.js:125:11) 
> at Object.basename (path.js:1289:5) 
> at Bucket.upload (/Users/apple/Desktop/Oner/social_app/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/storage/build/src/bucket.js:2237:38) 
> at PromiseCtor (/Users/apple/Desktop/Oner/social_app/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/promisify/build/src/index.js:71:28)
> at new Promise (<anonymous>) 
> at Bucket.wrapper (/Users/apple/Desktop/Oner/social_app/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/promisify/build/src/index.js:56:16) 
> at Busboy.busboy.on (/Users/apple/Desktop/Oner/social_app/functions/handlers/users.js:123:8) 
> at Busboy.emit (events.js:198:13) 
> at Busboy.emit (/Users/apple/Desktop/Oner/social_app/functions/node_modules/busboy/lib/main.js:37:33) 
> at /Users/apple/Desktop/Oner/social_app/functions/node_modules/busboy/lib/types/multipart.js:304:17
```

Comment: Was `file` callback fired before `finish` callback? Was mimetype equal to one of specified?

Comment: I don't know how to check that. I am sending post requests from Postman. But in the error message, it says the 124th line, which is `admin.upload(imageToBeUploaded.filepath,  {...  })`

Comment: Can you see logs in console? `console.log(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype);` Or of any `console.error`?

Comment: I meant in node console, not in postman console

Comment: Ok, I print console.logs, It logs before busboy.on but not after. It seems busboy.on method never fires and gives error

Comment: Based on given info I can only advice to add check in `finish` callback: `if (!imageToBeUploaded.filepath) return`, but that's not the solution you're looking for. `imageToBeUploaded = { filepath, mimetype };` seems to be not executed, but I can't tell why

Comment: I've one idea - look at the [examples](https://github.com/mscdex/busboy#examples), they all have `req.pipe(busboy);` where you have `busboy.end(req.rawBody);` - isn't it that you call `busboy.end` and it emits "finish" omiting "file" event?

Answer (score 1):

Anyone having the same issue, to fix it you have to rollback firebase-tools to previous version:

In functions folder

```
npm rm firebase-tools
npm i -g firebase-tools@6.8.0
```

Then add `config.storageBucket` to the `.bucket()` in the 'finish' event handler.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is Wrong in your code just remove Content-Type from postman headers.It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I understand you are trying to test ur code in postman. I faced same issue.
Genuine request:
Simply try to open new tab in POSTMAN, not duplicate, inherited from any other.
add image, add any other dependent headers like bearer token, etc and hit send.

I really don't know what went wront, but i think different headers in postman get added when playing with body type... and that causes problems.